# eclipse - search value of variable during debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, search, plugins

Does eclipse have a way, while debugging, to find variable when I know only its value? Or are there any plugins for this?
Thanks.

---

Sometimes I do not know where the variable is, but I know the value of the variable. If it is an object, I do not know all values or variables, but I know one value. So I would like to find this variable knowing its value.

Comment: Since nobody has even commented, I'll ask. Eclipse includes conditional break functionality, it only breaks if the expression evaluates at the breakpoint. Does this not give you what you need? If not, elaborate on your question.

Comment: @ahillman3: I think the OP is trying to find *which* variables hold a specific value...

Comment: yes, I would like to find variable with specific value. But I do not how and I cannot fing any plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I have long needed this kind of thing for exploring third-party code at a breakpoint. This eclipse plugin, [evars](http://code.google.com/p/evars/), seems to have potential, but I mostly end up with a very long-running search that results in an eclipse heap space error.

Comment: evars works for me, but using the variable export function rather than searching directly with the plugin. I installed the latest version into eclipse manually (put the jar in the dropins/plugins directory)

Answer (score 0):

If your values are object references, rather than primitive values, you can use the *All References* option in the menu that appears when you right-click on a value in the *Variables* view.

Answer (score -5):

Just hover the mouse over the varible. The value (if present) held by the variable is showed.

Comment: This will be useful only after the variable(s) can first be found.